# Summing on only the most recently added record

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this Django query. I could probably figure this out with SQL (and maybe I'll have to), but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with Django objects.

The model looks something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
class Stat(model.Models):
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I need to return the sum (using annotate and sum, I'm guessing) of all the most recently added quantities by a user, grouped by month. It's a little hard to explain, but the quantity is not cumulative -- I only need to deal with the most recent records for a given user and a given month, and then I need to sum those quantities, and group them by month. If more explanation is needed, please say so.

UPDATE:

Here's some rough psudo-code, as requested. This code is not necessarily what I would expect, but it's roughly what I could do if, but in a slow, programmatic way. I'm hoping there is a way to do this via a single query for the sake of speed. (BTW, this is based on Manoj Govindan's code below.)

```
year = list_of_months_that_have_stats
users = all_users_in_database
for months in year:
    for user in users:
        sum = Stat.object.filter(user=user, entry_date__month=month).order_by('-entry_date')[0].aggregate(sum=Sum('quantity'))
        final_output[month] = sum
```

Also, notice that I'm trying to get the very last record for the given month. I'm doing this with order_by, but as far as I know this won't work -- it's just an illustration.

The code above won't work, of course. The missing piece of the puzzle is the descending order_by that gets only the first item in the query.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo-code as to what you expect the process to look like?

Comment: It's a little hard to describe in pseudo-code because I'm honestly not sure how to approach it, but I'll try. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want. See my answer below and correct me if I am not getting it right.

> I only need to deal with the most recent records for a ***given user and a given month***, and then I need to sum those quantities, and group them by month.

(Emphasis added). If this is what you need, then you can use `filter` in combination with `aggregate`, as shown below.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
q = Stat.objects.filter(user = user, entry_date__month = 10).aggregate(
    sum = Sum('quantity'))
print q
# {'sum': 14}
```

The filter conditions ensure that you have the required `user` and that the `month` part of the `entry_date` matches the month you want (in this case October, therefore `10`). You can then `Sum` the quantity for the user/month combination.

**Update**

If you want the sum for an user **per each month** (I am guessing here that this is what you meant by "group them by month") then you can try something like this:

```
select = dict(month = 'extract(month from entry_date)')
q = Stat.objects.filter(user = user).extra(
      select = select).values('month').annotate(
      sum = Sum('quantity'))

print q
# [{'sum': 14, 'month': 10.0}, {'sum': 6, 'month': 9.0}]
```

Here is a quick explanation.

1. `extra` is used to specify that you want to extract the month part from the date. This is database specific. In my case the syntax `extract(month from entry_date)` is specific to Postgresql.
2. Use `values` to mention that you only need `month`. This is important. If you leave out the `values` part all fields are fetched and you won't get the effect you need.
3. Finally `annotate` each record with the `Sum('quantity')`. This returns the sum for each month.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's more or less what I need, except for one big difference: I need the very last record added, not simply a record with a specific date. So for August I need the most recent record added by a certain user. For September I need the same thing. Again, this is hard to explain, but thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: To explain further, what I mean by "last record added" is really the most recent record. Basically .order_by('-entry_date')[0], if you get what I mean.